# Enabling sorting in jQuery UI Sortable with connected lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a two `<ul>` lists connected up with **jQuery UI Sortable**.

I need items to be dragged and dropped from one list to the other and have used `connectWith: "ul"` as demonstrated below:

```
$("ul.droptrue").sortable({
   connectWith: "ul",
   receive: function (event, ui) {
   ...
```

This fires absolutely fine and works as expected.

How can I listen for reorder events within the individual lists themselves?

I tried using `sort: function (event, ui)`, however this seems to listen for all movement.

If anybody could suggest the best way to achive this, I'd appreciate it.

**Here are my lists**

```
<ul id="otpages1" class='droptrue'>
<li id="item-1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
<li id="item-1" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="otpages2" class='droptrue'>
<li id="item-2" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
<li id="item-2" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about the update event? That fires when the DOM position has changed between lists, as well as within a single list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This seems to fire twice is I drag and drop between ULs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
$(function () {
    var oldList, newList, item;
    $('ul.droptrue').sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            item = ui.item;
            newList = oldList = ui.item.parent();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {

        // perform action here

        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent();
        },
        connectWith: ".droptrue"
    }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `update` event of the *sortable*, which, as described in the [JQuery UI API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), contains a `null` value for the `sender` attribute when the sorting occurs in the same list.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update : function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.sender == null && ui.item.parent().is($(this))) {
            // Items were sorted within the same list
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
});
```